# Java very slow on win7

Tags: eclipse, performance, windows-7, java

I have a JSE project running on my WinXP 32 bit machine with JRE 1.6.0.29-b11 which is running just fine. The program is parsing XML files and writes them to the database. On the WinXP machine maybe 10-15 XML files are processed in one second. My eclipse version is 3.4.1

Now I got a new computer, which comes with Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.
I installed the new eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 64bit and JDK 6u30x64.
Then checked out my project throw subversion and compiled it. Now I need for one XML file almost 2 seconds, which is extremly slow. The new computer is a real power-mashine so the hardware should not be an issue. Just to see if the JREx64 ist the problem I downloaded JRE6u30x86 but the result was the same. Also I deleted the whole mashine and installed Win7 pro form scratch whith all the Java stuff. Nothing helped.

Now I am clueless what the problem can be. I am thankful for any help!

Comment: How much heap is configured for the JVM's?

Comment: You could look at this question to update the heap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse

Comment: What is a bottleneck? Have you seen at Task Manager, at least, which type or PC resources is consumed about 100%? Is CPU loaded on 100% or not? How many RAM is available for that process (and in total)? As another option, IO operations may be slow (due to an antivirus software or something like this) (BTW, what does your app consume more? CPU, RAM or IO operations?)

Comment: Never set it before. Is that it: -Xms40m -Xmx384m? I think then it is set on 40mb

Comment: My app consumes more of the CPU, which is workless at the moment. There is nothing which takes all the CPU load. Xean 2,93GHz CPU with 8GB of ram. I have kaspersky running on both mashines. I disabled it already to see if the kaspersky is the problem. Negative.

Comment: Did you check the following field: Resource Manager - HardDrive - Response time? (How much time the windows needs to reach a file) I had a very similar issue on my new machine, and as it turned out, it was the weak point of the system.

Comment: I can't find the Response time. You meen the Ressourcemonitor right?

Comment: Resourcemonitor... Sorry, localized windows. :) So: On the 4th Tab (harddrive), there are 3 panels. You can open them with a single click. The 2nd one must be "harddrive activity" or something like that. I tried to refer to the last column here.

Comment: what version of JDK are you running? 1.7.0_02 (1.7 update 2) by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Eclipse there exists also a known bug that is responsible for slow XML UI editor response times: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272

Sine a few days there exists a maintenance version that should solve this issue. It can be downloaded here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/M20121107-1200/eclipse-SDK-M20121107-1200-win32-x86_64.zip

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't launch your project from Eclipse or for that matter with Eclipse running. Eclipse takes a heavy load on the JDK, you don't need it if you're measuring 1/15 seconds lengths of time.

Second, make sure you're actually using the JDK you think you're using. In Eclipse, make sure it's selected as the project JDK (and the project is NOT in fact using the Eclipse bundled JDK). Do a `java -version` in a command prompt and see that the JDk you're using is Hotspot and the correct version, then launch your program from the command prompt.

I'm sure it's not a issue of Windows 7 or JDK. I've switched from XP to Win 7 64 with 64 bit Oracle JDK and I never noticed such slowdowns.

Comment: I'll try the commend-line, however on my old mashine I used eclipse the same way and it was that fast. Yes, I double checked the JDK version.

Comment: Also Wizart's comment is very pertinent. Make sure you have the same environment as before. Same (or none) antivirus, same database, same memory allocation for your program runtime etc etc.